# Sorting Records on a Custom calculated value at the runtime- rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have Two models `Product`, `Price`

```
Product 
 has_many :prices

Price
 belongs_to :product
```

we have `price_type` and `price_date` attributes in the `Price` Model. `price_type` can be **default**, **weekend**, **specific_date** for a particular `Product`.

*Product can have single price on a day like either it is weekend, or a specific_date otherwise default.*

`price_date` will be matter when `price_type` will be `specific_date`

Now The problem is,

`Date.today` is passing in the parameters

Means I want all the products with `price_type` is default and products of `price_type` weekend if its weekend and products which matches `specific_date` with passed date And sort them all in order of `price`

I'm trying to find the solution since a long time!

Please Help Me!

Thanks

Comment: so what you want is the all the products where `price_date == Date.today` , am I understanding your question?

Comment: Means you want all the products with price_type is `default` and products of price_type `weekend` if its weekend and products which matches `specific_date` with passed date And sort them all in order of `price` correct me if am wrong.

Comment: Yes @SujayGavhane ! You are right please help if possible I'm still in between!